# how to ajust the background pic according to outer div in css

Tags: css, html

```css
#container {width:1050px; height:106px;background:red;}
#image {background-image:url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg');height:106px;}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<div id="container">
 <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

**Question**

My background picture(logo.png), size is 1624*174, I want the pic adjust its height according to #container, e.g. if #container height: 106px, then pic size would be 989*106, if #container height: 200px, then pic size would be 1866*200, so basically I want to do is:

1. pic height= #container height
2. keep the proportion of pic width and height.

So how should i do?

Comment: Is it important to have the image in a separate `div`, rather than as the background of `#container`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) CSS rule on your BG `div`.

```css
background-size: contain;
```

Or for your exact use case, you can give it an advanced try:

```css
background-size: 106px, auto, cover;
```

Where, `106px` is the minimum, then horizontally it stretches and vertically it covers.

**Note:** This works only in new browsers.